# Get Logged-in User

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-rest

Please bare with me as I am learning Spring Data REST as I go. Definitely feel free to suggest a safer approach if what I am proposing here is not the safest approach or even possible.

**Problem**

A user logs into my Spring Data REST API via Google OAuth2. After logging in, I need to get the user's ID, which is just the value of their primary key, from the User table. The reason I need the ID is to restrict access to endpoints such as /users/{id}. If a user's ID is 1, then he is only allowed to view /users/1, unless he is an Administrator.

**Current Login Architecture**

This portion of the application works as expected:

[image]

OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler.java:

```
@Component("oauth2authSuccessHandler")
public class OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Autowired
    private UserDataRestRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RandomStringGenerator randomStringGenerator;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        OAuth2AuthenticationToken authenticationToken = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;

        String email = authenticationToken.getPrincipal().getAttributes().get("email").toString();

        if (!userRepository.existsByEmail(email)) {
            // If email not found, create local user account.

            String firstName = CaseUtils.toCamelCase(
                    authenticationToken.getPrincipal().getAttributes().get("given_name").toString().toLowerCase(),
                    true);

            String lastName = CaseUtils.toCamelCase(
                    authenticationToken.getPrincipal().getAttributes().get("family_name").toString().toLowerCase(),
                    true);

            // Generate temporary username.
            BigInteger usernameSuffix = userRepository.getNextValSeqUserUsername();
            String username = "User" + usernameSuffix;

            // Generate temporary password.
            String password = randomStringGenerator.generate(20).toUpperCase();

            // Encode Password.
            String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);

            User newUser = new User();
            newUser.setFirstName(firstName);
            newUser.setLastName(lastName);
            newUser.setUsername(username);
            newUser.setUserSetUsername(false);
            newUser.setEmail(email);
            newUser.setPassword(encodedPassword);
            newUser.setUserSetPassword(false);
            newUser.setCreated(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            newUser.setDisabled(false);
            newUser.setLocked(false);

            userRepository.save(newUser);
        }

        // Redirect to root page.
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/");
    }
}
```

UserDataRestRepository.java:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UserDataRestRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Integer>, CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
    
    public boolean existsByEmail(String email);

    @Query(value="SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Seq_User_Username", nativeQuery=true)
    public BigInteger getNextValSeqUserUsername();
}
```

OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler oauth2authSuccessHandler;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2Login()
                .successHandler(oauth2authSuccessHandler);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

**Database Tables**

User:

[image]

Role:

[image]

UserRole:

[image]

**Current Post-authentication Problems**

Currently, after a user logs in via OAuth2, we do not have access to the user's ID (which is the value of their primary key in the User table) unless we access the `Authentication` object, get the email address, then get the user's ID from the User table based on the email address. Basically: `Select Id from User where Email = user@example.com`

**Proposed Login Architecture**

I am wondering if the [UserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) can solve the problem, illustrated in green:

[image]

My train of thought is: by getting the user's info from the User table, then loading it into the `UserDetailsService`, the entire application now has access to the user's ID (primary key) and all of the other info in that row via the `UserDetailsService`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "I am wondering if the UserDetailsService can solve the problem, illustrated in green:" -- Yes! This is exactly the way to do it. You can put any info you want from the db in the `UserDetail` object, which will then be available in the `Authentication` object later.

Answer (score 1):

I would not include a round-trip to the DB for each incoming request on resource-server(s), this is a waste of resources.

Have you considered using an authorization-server in front of Google and either directly bound to your user database, or capable of calling a web-service to fetch additional data? Many propose it, along with "login with Google".

You would have complete control of access and ID tokens claims: you can add about anything as private claim, but the request to the DB (or Web-Service) happens only once per token issuance (and not once per request to a resource-server). And if you define an `Authentication` of your own (easy, just extend `AbstractAuthenticationToken`), you can put accessors to cast those private claims from `Object` to something more relevant to your security / domain model.

I demo something similar (add a private claim to access-token with a value returned by a web-service and then use it for access-control with custom `Authentication` and security DSL) in [this project](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies/tree/main/api).